# Cannot resolve all property references in the propertypath

Tags: wpf

I have a UserControl with a Border, the color of the border should be setted with a Dependency Property. I also want to animate the opacity of the border. My current xaml code looks like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding ElementName=ImageViewerUserControl, 
    Path=NotificationColor}"  BorderThickness="3" x:Name="AnimatedBorderBrush" 
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ImageViewerUserControl, 
    Path=ShowSequenceErrorNotification, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"> 
    <Border.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBorderBrush"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Opacity"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                        AutoReverse="True"
                        From="1"
                        To="0.0"
                        Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
</Border>
```

This only give the error:

> Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'BorderBrush.Opacity'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

But if I change to color of the BorderBrush to, lets say `Black` it works. How is this possible to achieve? I want to set the Brush color of my border via a dependency property. And yes, the dependency property is a `Brush`

Comment: Have you set a default Brush for your DependencyProperty? If not default value is null and will cause such an error.

Comment: @LPL How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the animation will only work if there is an object (the Brush) to animate. If you register your `DependencyProperty` without a default value it is null by default. Please try registering the DP with a default value

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NotificationColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "NotificationColor",
    typeof(Brush),
    typeof(ImageViewerUserControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent)
);
```

Edit:

And as @Sheridan says use `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"` instead of `Border.Opacity`. Although it works if you specify a direct `BorderBrush` it doesn't worked for me with a bounded DP.

Comment: Sounds like the solution but: I get this error message: Default value type does not match type of property 'NotificationColor'.

Comment: And what type is NotificationColor? Brush or Color?

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the same error message pops up during runtime. The property is Brush.

Comment: Jesus. It was just the namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your `AnimatedBorderBrush` name is misleading as it relates to a `Border` and *not* a `BorderBrush`. If you want to animate the `Border.Opacity`, then use `Border.Opacity` in the `DoubleAnimation` instead of `BorderBrush.Opacity`:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBorderBrush"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Border.Opacity"
    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
    AutoReverse="True"
    From="1"
    To="0.0"
    Duration="0:0:1" />
```

UPDATE >>>

Ahhhhh, my bad... As the animation is defined inside the `Border`, there is no need to reference it, just use `Opacity`:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedBorderBrush"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
    AutoReverse="True"
    From="1"
    To="0.0"
    Duration="0:0:1" />
```

Comment: I can see what you mean by the naming convention, I tried what you suggested, but no luck.

Comment: Your answer was correct, but the problem is that the guy over here also "fixed" my problem..Thanks alot!

Comment: Not a problem at all.